# For an array of instances, how does one, for each instance, invoke a certain method by this method's name?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, forwarding

I'm trying to pass the function behappy() of the Particle Class, as a parameter of the applyBehavior function of the ParticleSystem class. Am I missing some syntax ? I don't understand what is wrong with my calls.

Minimal reproducible code is here  and [here](https://editor.p5js.org/itsKaspar/sketches/GAsuJf_L-).

```js
class ParticleSystem{
  constructor(){
    this.particles = [];
    this.numberOfParticles = 10;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfParticles; i++){
      this.particles.push(new Particle());
    }
  }
  
  applyBehavior(behavior, message){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfParticles; i++){
      this.particles[i].behavior(message);
    }
  }
}

class Particle{
  constructor(){}
  behappy(message){
    print(message);
  }
}

let particlesys = new ParticleSystem();
particlesys.applyBehavior(behappy, "i am happy now");
```

expected output should be :

> "i am happy now" "i am happy now" "i am happy now" "i am happy now" "i
> am happy now" "i am happy now" "i am happy now" "i am happy now" "i am
> happy now" "i am happy now"

Comment: The Particle system related code which is supposed to *bulk apply* the behavior to each particle **does not assign** the behavior but tries to invoke it immediately. On the other hand. Any `Particle` instance already features a (prototypal) `behappy` method. Thus, in case `applyBehavior` is supposed to invoke a particle's method, one firstly should rename this method to `triggerBehavior` or `callBehavior` or `executeBehavior` and secondly needs to provide the particle's **method/behavior name** as first argument instead of (as of now) the function reference.

Comment: `execute(behaviorName, message) { ... this.particles[i][behaviorName](message); ...}`

Comment: The variable `behappy` that you pass to `applyBehaviour` is not defined. You need to pass a string: `particlesys.applyBehavior("behappy", "i am happy now");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case a particle system's `applyBehavior` is supposed to invoke a particle's method, one firstly should rename this method to `callBehavior`, `executeBehavior` or, even better, `executeParticles` and secondly needs to provide the particle's **method/behavior name** as first argument instead of a function reference.

**Edit**

As *Bergi* already did point to, one of cause has to assume that any method of a `Particle` instance most probably operates within a `Particle` instance's `this` context.

A `ParticleSystem`'s `executeParticles` method then has to be implemented in a way which explicitly provides such a context to any accessible `Particle` method. Since functions are object itself, they come with two methods which achieve exactly that ... [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). A target object can be provided to both methods. This target object does become the context of any method/function which gets invoked via `call`/`apply`.

The example code got changed accordingly, in order to show this use case ...

```js
class ParticleSystem{
  constructor(){
    this.particles = [];
    this.numberOfParticles = 10;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfParticles; i++){
      this.particles.push(new Particle(i));
    }
  }
  executeParticles(behaviorName, message){
    // for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfParticles; i++){
    //  this.particles[i][behaviorName](message);
    // }
    this.particles.forEach(particle => {
      const behavior = particle && particle[behaviorName];
      if (typeof behavior === 'function') {

        // MDN: "Function.prototype.call"
        // see: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call]

        behavior.call(particle, message);
      }
    });
  }
}

class Particle{
  constructor(idx){
    this.id = `particle_${ idx }`;
  }
  behappy(message){
    console.log(`${ this.id } logs ... "${ message }"`);
  }
}

let particlesys = new ParticleSystem();
particlesys.executeParticles('behappy', "I'am happy now.");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The most generic implementation of `executeParticles` which makes no assumptions about a particle method's arguments would utilize `apply` ...

```js
class ParticleSystem{
  constructor(){
    this.particles = [];
    this.numberOfParticles = 10;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfParticles; i++){
      this.particles.push(new Particle(i));
    }
  }
  executeParticles(behaviorName, ...args){
    this.particles.forEach(particle => {
      const behavior = particle && particle[behaviorName];
      if (typeof behavior === 'function') {

        behavior.apply(particle, args);
      }
    });
  }
}

class Particle{
  constructor(idx){
    this.id = `particle_${ idx }`;
  }
  behappy(message){
    console.log(`${ this.id } logs ... "${ message }"`);
  }
}

let particlesys = new ParticleSystem();
particlesys.executeParticles('behappy', "I'am happy now.");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This does not work for methods that use the `this` keyword

Comment: To me, this requirement is implicit in "invoke a method on an instance". No matter what the method does.

Comment: Thanks! Using `call` should not be necessary though, `particle[behaviorName]()` would be much simpler